# ROR: Nested Resources: NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for, nested-resources

In my application teams are created to solve a challenge. Once the team is created, members can join that team.

Everything works when creating the challenge -> the team, but when it comes to adding the team member that is when I receive this error:

**Error**

NoMethodError in Team_members#new

Showing /home/vincent/solvabl/app/views/team_members/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

```
undefined method `team_team_members_path' for #<#<Class:0x9bdadcc>:0xa179df0>
```

Extracted source (around line #1):

```
1: <%= form_for([@challenge,@team,@team_member]) do |f| %>
2:   <% if @team_member.errors.any? %>
3:     <div id="error_explanation">
4:       <h2><%= pluralize(@team_member.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this team_member from being saved:</h2>
```

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/team_members/new.html.erb

Rails.root: /home/vincent/solvabl
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

```
app/views/team_members/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_team_members__form_html_erb___477348688_81202980'
app/views/team_members/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_team_members_new_html_erb___135218923_85112930'
app/controllers/team_members_controller.rb:36:in `new'
```

Request

Parameters:

```
{"challenge_id"=>"1",
 "team_id"=>"1"}
```

Show session dump

Show env dump
Response

Headers:

```
None
```

**Routes**

```
resources :challenges do
  resources :teams do
    resources :team_members
  end
end
```

**Controller**

```
def create
    @team_member = TeamMember.new(params[:team_member])
    @team_member.team_id = @team.id
    @team_member.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @team_member.save
        format.html { redirect_to [@team,@team_member], notice: 'Team member was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: [@team,@team_member], status: :created, location: [@team,@team_member] }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @team_member.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**View**

```
<%= form_for([@team,@team_member]) do |f| %>
  <% if @team_member.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@team_member.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this team_member from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @team_member.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :team_id %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :team_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :user_id %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :user_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routes you have will give you `challenges_team_team_members_path`.  In order to get `team_team_members_path` add the following to your `config/routes.rb`:

```
resources :teams do 
  resources :team_members
end
```

**Update:**

Please note that this addition should be in addition to what you've already defined.  So, your `routes.rb` would have:

```
resources :challenges do
  resources :teams do
    resources :team_members
  end
end

resources :teams do 
  resources :team_members
end
```

Comment: Thank you vinodadhikary this actually makes a lot of sense. I am going to try this when I get back to my computer. I will let you know if this works. Thanks again!